# How to send private messages or locate a specific user?

Tags: support, private-messaging

I'm a 17-year-old girl living in Mexico and dreaming of studying at a university in Romania. I speak Spanish and English and am trying my best to learn Romanian, and I can hardly find anyone to whom I can speak in Romanian. My only Romanian e-friend who's actually willing to help won't Skype with me because he lives with his family and the time difference means he'd wake them if we were to Skype at a decent time for me.

Now that you know this, you can imagine my excitement when I randomly found an *active* user with a totally Romanian name, Bogdan Alexandru, and even more so when I clicked his profile and found that he is indeed from București. But he has no contact links on his profile. Is there any way I can contact him and offer to trade services (like an I'll-help-you-with-Spanish-if-you-help-me-with-Romanian thing)? Or will I just have to put something on my profile, answer one of his questions and hope he looks at my page?

Answer (score 12):

This is not possible.

Why? Because we are not a social network. And we are not interested in becoming one. We focus on questions and answers, under specific topics.

If a user has not shared any contact details publicly, it is most probably because they don't want to be contacted by strangers.

> Or will I just have to put something on my profile, answer one of his questions and hope he looks at my page?

By all means, put something on your profile.

**However**, unless you have an actual, relevant answer to a post by this person, you shouldn't answer. Doing anything else would be rude by our standards.

Comment: So how do I edit /my/ profile to post my contact info and interest in speaking to Romanians? I couldn't find a button :(

Comment: There is an "edit" link.

Comment: I couldn't find it...would someone please kindly point me to it? Or maybe I'm just overtired right now.<br /><br />"...unless you have an actual, relevant answer to a post by this person, you shouldn't answer. Doing anything else would be rude by our standards." Of course I understand that, which is why I refrained from doing so. ;) I do know a bit of netiquette, I just need to polish it up a bit. ;)

Comment: Here it is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpu1y.png

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you :p I couldn't see it. *facepalm*

Comment: @PrincessKiara :  Nice "profile page" content! But to be honest: maybe a bit too much (maybe you should try to condense it a bit). Regarding "Feel free to e-mail me" ... Are you sure you included an eMail ID ? By the way: by adding that @ followed by your username, this "comment" here should have triggered some type msg to you (even though I don't have your eMail iD). And of course that is not "private", but at least some type of "hello", no? Looking at your profile it seems you haven't visited the "tour" yet (via the help upper right). Consider doing so (you'll even receive a badge for it).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I will, thank you :D I did include an e-mail, but in case it isn't showing publicly, it's princeszkiara@gmail.com :p I know I need to learn to condense more when I write xD Too much detail. And the @  thingy only works when the person commented on the same question :(